# New computer with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS will not connect in a useful way to Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: usb, samsung

When I plug in the phone into the computer and answer the prompt on the phone to give permission for the computer to read the information on the phone, the files window opens, but it is constantly loading, with no files or folders every showing up.

An lsusb at the command line generates this output:

> Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>   Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0316 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
>   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:009a Synaptics, Inc.
>   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:2113 Acer, Inc
>   Bus 001 Device 016: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
>   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Any ideas?

Edit: I just discovered that if you wait long enough (maybe an hour?) the files and folders finally show up. Surely this must indicate some abnormality in connection? Also when navigating into a folder on the phone to see the contents it seems the **long** wait begins again.

Comment: Check out `GSConnect` GNOME extension, and `KDE Connect` at the Google Play Store.

Comment: The long time is perhaps justified by the need to install support for MTP/PTP. After reboot and with the system up to date, it should work as expected.

Comment: None of these suggestions worked. KDE connect never sees the computer and rebooting did not change anything. The computer is up to date - it is very new (about a week old).

Comment: Did you install `GSConnect` on the computer, and `KDE Connect` on the phone? Did you set the prefs? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll probably miss them.

Comment: @heynema ... cool. I did get this going as you suggested when i was more careful (and followed the GSConnect instructions more carefully. Thanks you again for the help! Cheers, Kevin